# Is there a way to avoid having to pass both $ and $foo when using .each() inside a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am using cheerio to do some web scraping. There is a scenario that I want to get a table from a web page, and extract certain info I need.

For example

```
const $table = $("table").eq(3);
```

Now I have a `$table` cheerio object. Since I'll use the table's data several times, I want to turn it into something simpler. I have defined something like this

```
// a row of the table
function PlayDataEntry(no, title, bmsid, clear, ranking) {
    this.no = no;
    this.title = title;
    this.bmsid = bmsid;
    this.clear = clear;
    this.ranking = ranking;
}
```

I would like to turn `$table` into an array of `PlayDataEntry`.

So now I need to do some traversing:

```
PlayDataEntry.createFromTable = function($, $table) {
    const $rows = $table.find("tr")
                        .not(":has('th')"); // no header row
    const entries = [];
    $rows.each((i, el) => {
        const $row = $(el);
        const entry = PlayDataEntry.createFromRow($row);
        entries.push(entry);
    });
    return entries;
};
```

And I'll use it like this

```
// ... some requests ...
.then(($) => {
    const $table = MyList.getPlayDataTable($);
    const entries = PlayDataEntry.createFromTable($, $table);
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        console.log(entry.toString());
    });
})
```

But I feel having to pass `$, $table` is very awkward. The only reason I have to is because cheerio's `each()` gives me a bare element so I have to use $() again. I can make another method that directly receives a $ and returns an array of `PlayDataEntry`, but before that I would like to know is there other ways to avoid `$, $table`?

Comment: Since you're using a class, can you instantiate the class with `$` passed to the constructor?